# Create list with random and unique numbers

Tags: random, erlang, elixir, unique

I'm trying to make a list of unique, random integers of a certain length.

```
end_list = for x <- 0..10, do: :rand.uniform(50)
> [41, 9, 8, 50, 49, 1, 1, 7, 7, 47, 20]
```

What can I write to convey an "if not already present" condition in the `do:` block?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I was offered this one-liner using [`Stream.repeatedly/1`](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/Stream.html#repeatedly/1) from somewhere else:

```ex
Stream.repeatedly(fn -> :rand.uniform(50) end) |> Stream.uniq |> Enum.take(10)
```

Comment: This is the correct answer, it return 10 elements in every iteration and every item is unique.

Answer (score 3):

You could use [MapSet](https://hexdocs.pm/elixir/MapSet.html) for it, which will add an element only if it doesn't exist. Then, in the end, you could transform the MapSet to list.

Something like this would work:

```
ms = for x <- 0..10, into: MapSet.new(), do: :rand.uniform(50)
end_list = MapSet.to_list(ms)
[2, 10, 15, 16, 19, 28, 34, 43, 48]
```

Comment: I this is a good solution, but it doesn't get 10 elements in every iteration.